# Why does Django display anonymous user after login?

Tags: python, django, audio

TL;DR: Django's request.user returns an anonymous user when browsing from Android mobile, after a user has logged in, when the URL is used as an HTML5 audio src attribute.

I am working on a website that serves audio files. When a user goes to play an audio file, the site first checks that they are logged in, and then if they own the rights to the audio. I am confident that the user is correctly logged in, because they are able to see all of the things a logged in user would see. Although when the view to access the audio is hit, the site returns an anonymous user response.

This is my view code:

```
def getAudio(request, pd_id):
    print request.user

    pd = PdSession.objects.get(pk=pd_id)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        owned_sessions = [purchase.pdsession for purchase in request.user.profile.purchase_set.all()]
        if request.user.profile.is_presenter == True:
            created_sessions = request.user.presenter.pdsession_set.all()
            owned_sessions = list(chain(created_sessions, owned_sessions))

        if pd in owned_sessions or request.user.is_superuser:
            if pd.pdaudio:
                name = os.path.basename(pd.getAudioLocation())
            else:
                name = os.path.basename(pd.getAudioLocation().url)

            response = HttpResponse()
            response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(name)
            response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/content/{0}".format(name)
            return response
```

Which is called from my template like so:

```
<audio id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
    <source src="{% url 'audio' pd.id %}" type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

The user must be logged in to even get to this html page, so I don't understand why the view is acting as though they are an anonymous user. I can tell this by the print line I've inserted. If I remove the restriction on checking for authentication/ownership, it works, so I don't think it has to do with the response headers.

What is even more strange, is if I directly go to the URL of the audio view, the audio file will download and play, meaning the view recognizes that the user is logged in. It feels like my set-up isn't working properly because it is used as a src URL and not a direct request? That is my gut feel.

To make matters even more complicated, this problem only happens on mobile. On all major browsers for desktop computers, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but to shorten some of your code you can change `if request.user.profile.is_presenter == True:` to just `if request.user.profile.is_presenter:`. Sorry I can't be more helpful :(

Comment: Can you show us the request headers sent by the browser when requesting this view - i.e., the contents of `request.META`?

Comment: @solarissmoke Sure, I uploaded them to [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/RHB3neJx). There was also a gstatic(?) header that I've excluded, but I don't think it should make a difference as the mobile header in question is the one failing I believe. I didn't know what to look for beyond the session ID and red flags, but there are some differences between the two headers. Maybe one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: I can't see anything there that would cause a problem. Bump.